# myBatis ORACLE - trying to load a temporary table and then run a select statement against it

Tags: oracle, mybatis, ibatis, sqlmap

The example below was greatly simplified to illustrate the problem I am facing.  What I am trying to do is to load an ORACLE temporary table and then run a query against that table using myBatis.  Its quite possible I am forgetting some basics of ORACLE when preparing this statement, its been a little while... At any rate, I have used this same approach to populate temporary tables in SQL Server and Sybase, but I am having trouble setting up the correct syntax for this to work in ORACLE.  Any thoughts what I am doing wrong here?

```
<select id="myTest"  resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap"  fetchSize="1000">
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO mySessionTable (a,b) VALUES (1,1);
     INSERT INTO mySessionTable (a,b) VALUES (2,1);
     INSERT INTO mySessionTable (a,b) VALUES (3,1);
   END;

   SELECT a, b FROM mySessionTable;        
</select>
```

Comment: such a code block is nonsense. either you excute anonymous pl/sql block or you execute select/dml statement. but not both.

Comment: Even if you put the select statement into the pl/sql block it would not work. Oracle does not support "impicit" return variables from pl/sql.

Comment: Could I declare and open a REF CURSOR within the block to get the results back?

Comment: Yes. But 2nd simple pure select would be much easier to implement.